# Unexpected behavior with strings comparision python

Tags: string, python-3.x, comparison

This is a very simple function in Python

```
def not_string(str1):
    if str1[0:3] is "not":
        return str1
    else:
        return 'not ' + str1

str1 = 'not bad'
print(not_string(str1))
```

The output of the above code should be "not bad" but the Python is showing output as "not not bad. Can anyone explain what I am missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `is` operator in Python tests for object equality rather than value equality. What you want is for your if statement to be `if str1[0:3] == "not":`